Duplicate entity error when creating entities with multiple VUs in k6
I am quite new to k6 and we have the following edge case.
We need to create a big amount of data for a reasonably good time.
The entity that we are trying to create has an array of Uids(permissionsUids) as a payload for which there cannot be a duplicate permutation and I am getting the permissions(set of 10) via a GET request and generating all the possible permutations(1023) which are returned as an array of arrays.
The problem is that due to the concurrency sometimes the VUs try to create the entity with data that is already created by another VU and I think this might be normal and how k6 lifecycle works as this is quite an edge case but I wanted to be sure.
I have the following options in k6:
export const options = {
    vus: 100,
    iterations: 1023
};

My setup method gets and returns all the combinations in an array of arrays.
And in my default function I did the iterationsPerVU and uniqueIndex calculations in order to narrow the failed requests down to being between 2%-5%:
    const iterationsPerVU = Math.floor(options.iterations / options.vus);
    const uniqueIndex = (__VU - 1) * iterationsPerVU + __ITER;

With the uniqueIndex I am just getting the element from the array of arrays variable and trying to create the entity with it.
Again I guess this might be an edge case and k6 might not be the tool for this but would be glad if there is an answer to this either being beneficial one or not.
Thank you for your time reading this, have a nice day!

Have you had a look at https://grafana.com/docs/k6/latest/examples/data-parameterization/#retrieving-unique-data or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78424855/using-unique-parameterized-data-with-multiple-scenarios?

Hey @knittl, thank you for your reply. I have tried the first suggestion and having a shared array doesn't seem to resolve the issue. The idea is that each VU should send an unique permutation which is not sent by any VU yet.
The second suggestion will not work because I have a dynamically populated array.

I'm not sure I understand. In your question you present a solution that already works in 95%–98% of the time. The first link shows how to use scenario.iterationInTest to get a unique index in the test. So instead of using __VU and __ITER (which is per VU), use iterationInTest (which is per scenario). You already have your array (created in your setup, as written in your question). By using the unique iteration index, you can access the items in your array. What am I missing?

Even with SharedArray I am still getting the duplicate API error(I want 100% request success) while using the iterationInTest and the array is being initialized on global level before the setup method is ran and in my current case I don't even have a setup method because of this restriction. If I just have an array of arrays it will be initialized in the setup method but I won't be able to specify the iterations in the 'options object, even if I hardcoded the iterations, I doubt it that the outcome would be different(I guess the SharedArray is not as shared as it seems).

You have not presented a [mre], so I can only make assumptions. Nevertheless, I have answered with a script that I have verified locally to work (each index is used exactly once).

scenario.iterationInTest of k6/exeuction gives you access to the unique iteration index in the current scenario.
You can then easily index into a prepopulated shared array:
import { SharedArray } from 'k6/data';
import { scenario } from 'k6/execution';

export const options = {
    vus: 100,
    iterations: 1023,
};

const data = new SharedArray('numbers', () => {
    return [...Array(1023).keys()];
});

export default function() {
    console.log(`item: ${data[scenario.iterationInTest]}`);
    console.log(`VU: ${__VU}`);
    console.log(`ITER: ${__ITER}`);
}

If you check the logs, you will see that each item of the array is printed exactly once.

Yes, you are right, sorry about my previous reply, sometimes when testing I forgot to call the previous script that gives me all the permutations in a JSON format(as I could not do it with k6 because of the requests that needed to be made and SharedArray does not allow that so I needed to do it with Node and axios) based on which I initialize the SharedArray by reading the output.json. There are like < 1% failures but this is due to some application translation and DB issues which is not related to k6.
Thank you for your help and time looking into this, appreciate it!
